# Positive elements in tensorproduct of C*-Algebras

Tags: tensor-products, operator-algebras

Let $\mathcal{A}$, $\mathcal{B}$ be two unital (non-commutative) $C^{*}$-Algebras. Then it is a well-known fact that in general not every positive element $\rho \in \mathcal{A} \otimes \mathcal{B}$ (i.e. there exists $x \in \mathcal{A} \otimes \mathcal{B}$ s.t. $\rho = x^{*} x$) admits a representation
$$ \rho = \sum_{i=1}^{m} a_i^{*} a_i \otimes b_i^{*} b_i$$
where $a_i \in \mathcal{A}$, $b_i \in \mathcal{B}$, i.e. a sum of positive elements.
Now I have read that if we restrict to the case where at least one of the two spaces is commutative, then, every positive element can be decomposed in the above way.
I have already tried the following naive approach:

Assume $\mathcal{A}$ is commutative. For $\rho \geq 0$ there exists an element $x \in \mathcal{A} \otimes \mathcal{B}$ such that $\rho = x^{*} x$ with decomposition
$$ x = \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i \otimes b_i$$
But I don't see whether the mixed of the elementary tensors in the product $x^{*} x$ are positive and neither how I can use the commutativity of $\mathcal{A}$.

EDIT: Assume that $\mathcal{A}, \mathcal{B}$ are finite-dimensional to guarantee that every element in the tensor product space can be written as a finite sum of elementary tensors.

Comment: After assuming that $\mathcal A$ is commutative, how do you get that $x$ lies in the algebraic tensor product?

Comment: Since $\mathcal{A} \otimes \mathcal{B}$ is again a C*-algebra, the existence of $x$ defines the positivity of $\rho$. Or what do you mean exactly?

Answer (score 1):

This can't even be true in the commutative setting.  If every positive element of $A\otimes B$ was of the form $\sum a^*_ia_i\otimes b^*_ib_i$, then every $x\in A\otimes B$ is of the form $\sum a_i\otimes b_i$, i.e., $A\odot B=A\otimes B$.  But this is not true in general, even in the commutative case.

Comment: I don't see the argument. What happens with the mixing terms $a_i^* a_j \otimes b_i^{*} b_j$ if you spell out $x^{*} x$?

Comment: @AndreasK The point is that the minimal (or any) C*-tensor product is much much larger than the algebraic tensor product. Not every positive element can be written as a finite sum of tensors. If this were the case, then as positives span, every element would be a finite sum of pure tensors, from which it would follow that both $A$ and $B$ were finite-dimensional.

Comment: Whoops, I meant one of $A$ or $B$ would be finite-dimensional.

Comment: Ok, of course, sorry I didn't take this technical detail into account. But what happens in the finite-dimensional case? I will edit the question accordingly.